# How to inspect a element in a drop down menu in chrome and firefox?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome, firefoxdriver

The problem here is when we hover the mouse over the particular menu item, drop down items going to visible. When trying to click the inspect element the drop down items are not going to be visible.

How can I inspect this drop down menu items

Comment: Can you share a screenshot and the DOM of the page/related ares.

Comment: You will need to open the developer tool side by side with your webpage, hover your mouse over the particular menu item and at the same time, inspect the element displayed in the developer tool. If this still does not work, you will make an educated guess by selecting the child of of this menu item.

Comment: Where it happens? If its an Salesforce Lightning website then there is different mechanism to view dropdown options and if its other than that you can simply find all the options within the Select class with option tag.

Comment: Use selenium IDE and record the steps for selecting items from dropdown.
By looking at that code, you might be able to prepare your own code.

Answer (score 0):

To make drop-down visible and inspect the elements under the drop-down, In the automation testing company we use to set

```
drop-down-content {
    display: none;
}
```

to "**block**" in HTML while inspecting element, So that drop-down did not disappears. or set display none check box to uncheck under DOM. Hope this solution works for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To inspect a element in a drop-down menu in Chrome and Firefox, follow the given steps-

- In Chrome and Firefox, we can right click on element and click on inspect
- When drop down menu is open, we can Pause browser by using F8 key from keyboard
- Once browser is paused, we can again right click on drop down values and inspect it.